# php utf8 text doesnt render correctly

Tags: php, mysql, substr

I have a table where i have a TEXT column in utf8_unicode_ci format.

I also have a form where i can put multi language text into this field.

When i fetch each text from this column i want to show only 50 characters in length so i do the following:

```
$text = $rows["text"];
$text = mb_substr($text, 0, 50);
$text = htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

this fails to render non english characters and doesnt show anything, if i put mb_substr function below htmlentities it will show up but it will cut the text and show some &letter;&another;

any way i can solve this issue?

Comment: What *exactly* does the output look like? Why are you using `htmlentities()` in the first place?

Comment: i need to use htmlentities due to xss code. if i enter for example some sample text like this: "σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σσ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ" it wont show anything because it breaks... if i remove htmlentities it will show the following: "σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σ σσ σ σ σ � " if i remove the substr and leave htmlentities it will work correctly but i need to limit the amount of characters to 50.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` will suffice to prevent XSS, no need to turn every character into entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mb_internal_encoding](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) to change the char encoding to UTF-8, that might solve it.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: i have putted it into my config file which is loaded in every file and it seems to solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on mySQL < 5.0.7:

Enable utf -8 while querying using 
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

if you're on a newer mySQL:

mysql_set_charset("utf8");

AND

header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8');